# ServiceStack Razor Response Filter

Tags: asp.net, servicestack

I Write a ServiceStack Razor Page named 'default.cshtml'. I want to add a global response filter on it running, but it not work right. how to fixed it?

[image]

```
    private static void AddFilters(IAppHost appHost)
    {
        appHost.GlobalResponseFilters.Add((req, res, dto) =>
        {
           res.AddHeader("X-Powered-By", "mylvgth");
         });
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GlobalResponseFilters are for requests that populate Request DTOs and are executed by Services. For other requests you can use PreRequestFilters which is executed at the start of a Request.

There are no Response filters for Razor pages as you can’t add Headers to a Request after its already written to the Response, only for “View Pages” which call Services first where the Response filter is executed before the page is rendered.